# Eclipse CDT : don't print to screen until input first

Tags: eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

Here is my simple code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
        printf("Hello new world\n");
        char c[10];
        scanf("%s",c);
        printf("%s",c);
        return 0;
    }
```

Normal, We will see: `Hello new world`, after that, we input some string, and C will print this string for us.

But in my eclipse CDT, when running, console is empty. I must input a string first, for example, `stackoverflow`. after that, my program will print :

```
Hello new world
stackoverflow
```

I don't know why happen, please teach me to fix this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something that developers of Eclipse do not consider for a bug.

You can read more about this "bug" here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732

Anyway... Ugly but working solution is to put

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after every printf() and puts().